# ACRA seems to be reporting crashes from Handled exceptions

Tags: java, android, debugging, acra

We have been using ACRA to report crashes in our app, however it seems sometimes it reports crashes where we have already handled exceptions in code. Is this a feature of ACRA, and if so, can we set it to ignore handled exceptions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for ACRA to react to handled Exceptions. You must be mistaken.

The only way that ACRA could be forwarding on handled Exceptions is if you have explicitly invoked `ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(e)`

Otherwise ACRA only receives notifications from the System UncaughtExceptionhandler.

Comment: I would have thought the same thing.  But there are cases where we are getting crashes from code that is clearly dealing with the exception involved. We have a very large user base, and there is lots of data to back this up.

Comment: For that to have happened, either you are explicitly reporting the Exception to ACRA, or some library you are using is explicitly reporting the error to ACRA.